# Import/Export data using ETL or Java Freamework

Tags: java, import, export, kettle

We want to add the ability to Import/Export data in our java webapp (implemented using Spring and Hibernate). 
Our webapp contains hierarchical data along with LOB data loaded from files.
The requirement is to export the data into XML/binary files, bundle everything up in a ZIP file and import it into another instance of our application.

Do you have any experience or suggestions on which frameworks should I use in order to implement this (if any exist)?

I taught of using Pentaho's data integration (Kettle), but I think that it would be hard to test and maintain it, so I'm looking for any other java framework that might do the trick in order to compare between the two.

Comment: What database vendor(s) are we talking about?  Also is it a one off to build a new environment or constantly keeping another environment up to date?

Comment: Currently we use Oracle, but it might change in the future. It is a one off operation generally used for post installation setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle then I suggest that you use the [data pump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/dp_api.htm) features of [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) to do it. This will be much more reliable and straight forward then trying to implement something yourself and in my experience it's best to use the native migration features of your database.

I have some experience with Kettle and that could be a good option if you need to do some transformation, i.e., actual ETL, as part of the migration although, like you said, it's more difficult to test.

EDIT:
If you need to make this part of a whole environment setup then I suggest you combine it with [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) or [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) which can bootstrap the whole lot including app server, properties files, database scripts, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see now that I forgot to mention it, but one of the requirements is to copy locally stored files between the servers (they should be part of the ZIP file I mentioned). Because of that I don't want to split the implementation into 2 different tools and stick to only one. In addition, I'll also have a problem in case our database will change in the future.

Comment: If you are trying to bootstrap a whole environment then I would suggest using scripting to achieve it instead. You can still use Data Pump in it's scripted form but make it part of a Puppet or Chef setup. I'm using Puppet and it works really well.

Comment: Sounds interesting, i'll take a look. Thanks a lot.